# How can i request http actions fast in java (minimal overhead)

Tags: java, performance, rest, http, httpclient

I am trying to send PUT/POST requests to my server and measure the round trips.
I am attaching a fairly large body (5k json elements) on each request.

Doing it in my daily framework takes a long time (using rest-assured, hamcrests, , prettyfying json result, etc). So I am looking for a way to make my requests overhead as short as possible.

I can see that the requests are very fast in dhc/postman, but I can't get that speed even when I use HttpClient as follows :

```
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://XXX/rest/"+url);
    httppost.addHeader(Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER,Constants.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE);
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity(str);
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization","XXXX");
    httppost.setEntity(params);
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I get slower result than when I run it through DHC/Postman
Thanks

Comment: What is the difference in speed related to? Server response time (i.e. time spent in your last line of code) or overall test execution? If the latter applies, are you by chance instantiating your HTTP client in a for loop?